# Angular: Dynamically Setting the Id with ng-repeat and ng-attr-id

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to set the id of an anchor tag with a value that is used in my ng-repeat. {{channel}} should include a string with the channel number. {{channel}} is displayed fine as the text within the anchor tag, however for the id, the id is empty, does anyone know how I can implement this properly?

```
<li ng-repeat="channel in vm.channels">
    <a ui-sref="channel({channel:channel, event: null})" ng-attr-id="{{channel}}" ui-sref-active="active">{{managedContent 'channel'}} \{{channel}}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: If I change it to ng-attr-id="channel", then the id is actually just set to the word "channel" not the string that is stored within the variable called channel.

Comment: Sorry, my first comment was wrong you need the brackets. But your id will be set with the value of channel but ng-attr-id will be like in the html above ng-attr-id="{{channel}}". This is what I get on my site. <div ng-attr-id="{{obj.id}}" class="ng-binding" id="1">1</div> the id is set to 1 like it should

Comment: The issue is that in mine ng-attr-id="{{channel}}" leaves the id blank, it's not being set to the value within "channel" as expected.

Comment: What is your "channel" I just tried object also and get a json object in id <div ng-attr-id="{{obj}}" class="ng-binding" id="{"id":"1","name":"A"}">1</div>  What data do you have in channel. Probably that is the issue.

Comment: Channel is just a string, like "53", as you can see in html above it is being repeated for every channel in vm.channels, vm.channels is an array of strings.

Comment: Strange, can you recreate your issue like on codepen, plunker or here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-qunzyn?file=home%2Fhome.html

Comment: Really strange, i've replicated it there and it works as expected. I'll probably have to come back to this at some point. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <div class="accordion" [attr.id]="'accordionTwo_' + i" *ngFor=" let i = index; let message of messages">

    <button class="btn btn-info pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-parent]="'#accordionTwo_' + i" [attr.href]="'#collapseTwo_' + i"> Details </button>
    <div [attr.id]="'collapseTwo_' + i" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <h1>Expanded body</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Try the above code for *ngFor accordion.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
ng-attr-id="{{ '' + channel }}"
```

Or simply:

```
id="{{ channel }}"
```